# Java for each statement

Tags: java, vb.net, oop

I'm really good with VB and I have a project where I need to check an array. If the same item in an array exists twice or more it needs to be changed to an item that doesn't exist. Now I'm in a class where they're making us use Java for this project.

I was wondering what is the equivalent of a for each loop in Java? I checked the JavaDocs and it only had info for the regular for loop, I didn't notice any section that said anything about a for each loop.

Answer (score 1):

It's more subtle in Java than VB.  You can find the official docs in the Oracle documentation here (towards the bottom):

[Java For Loops](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html)

The provided example is:

```
// Returns the sum of the elements of a

int sum(int[] a) {
    int result = 0;
    for (int i : a)
        result += i;
    return result;
}
```

Hope that helps.  Be careful not to remove or add elements inside the loop or you will get a Concurrent Modification Exception.

Comment: Cool, what is the "a" value?

Comment: In this case, it's a parameter of the sum function.  It is a variable length array of integers.  'for' can work on any collection.  Arrays, linked lists, etc.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 String arr [] = // you decide how this gets initialized

 for (String obj: arr) {
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is called "iterating over collections". An array can be implicitly converted to a collection, so you can iterate over an array in the same way, using the "enhanced for-loop".

```
List<String> names = new LinkedList<>();

// ... add some names to the collection

for(name:names) {
  System.out.println(name);
}
```

I'm not sure if VB has collections - they are a big part of Java and I recommend you look into them.

Of course this changes a bit in Java 8, although you'll notice a collection is still the backbone of forEach().

```
List<String> names = new LinkedList<>();

// ... add some names to the collection

names.forEach(name -> System.out.println(name));
```

Answer (score 0):

A `for each` loop (also known as `the enhanced for loop`) is as follows:

```
for (String name : names) {
    // here, the loop will work over each element of 'names',
    // with the variable name with which to access each element
    // being 'name', and output it
    System.out.println(name);
}
```

A normal `for loop` is as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
     // here, i will iterate until max, then the loop will stop.
     // any array access here has to be done manually using i, which increments.
}
```

If insertion order from the names array is important, keep adding the objects to a [`LinkedHashSet<String>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html), then with either a for loop or enhanced for loop or iterator, go over your list of names and add each of them to the `LinkedHashSet`. If the `add` method, passing in your name, returns `false`, generate a new name and add that.

If insertion order is not important, use a `HashSet<String>` instead.

At the end, convert back to an array if it is important (`String[] bla = map.toArray(new String[0])`), or output the `toString()` of the map.

Comment: for (name name : names)  ==> for (String name : names)